# Build error on fresh Flutter and Dart installation (import error)

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new in Flutter and install it with Dart from zero. When I'm building a basic example like this:

```
    import 'packafe:flutter/material.dart';

void main(){
  runApp(
    title: "Mi Primer Aplicación",
    home: new Scaffold(
       appbar: new AppBar(
         title: new Text("Mi Primer aplicación")
       ), // AppBar
       body: new Container(
        child: new Center(
          child: new text("Hello World")
        ) // Center
       )
    )
  )
}
```

I get this error, i have to say that i can run the example that you get when creating a new Flutter proyect.

```
Invalid depfile: C:\Users\rodri\Documents\Cursos\Proyectos Flutter - Dart\primer_app_bien\.dart_tool\flutter_build\2b50f4f217897948359897bb9975b24c\kernel_snapshot.d
Invalid depfile: C:\Users\rodri\Documents\Cursos\Proyectos Flutter - Dart\primer_app_bien\.dart_tool\flutter_build\2b50f4f217897948359897bb9975b24c\kernel_snapshot.d
lib/main.dart:1:8: Error: Error when reading 'packafe:flutter/material.dart': StandardFileSystem only supports file:* and data:* URIs
import 'packafe:flutter/material.dart';
       ^
lib/main.dart:8:21: Error: Method not found: 'Text'.
         title: new Text("Mi Primer aplicación")
                    ^^^^
lib/main.dart:7:20: Error: Method not found: 'AppBar'.
       appbar: new AppBar(
                   ^^^^^^
lib/main.dart:12:22: Error: Method not found: 'text'.
```

It's the first time I install Flutter, Dart, Android Studio and Visual Code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the `material` package in other to use `Material` widgets in your application.

In your import statement, you spelt `package` as `packafe` which is wrong.

I added a working code (using your code as an example), replace it with yours:

```
// import the package correctly
import 'package:flutter/material.dart'; // new line

// main method
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}


// create a stateless widget and build your widget tree
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: new Text("Mi Primer aplicación")), // AppBar
        body: Container(
          child: Center(
            child: Text("Hello World"),
          ), // Center
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

NOTE: With [Dart 2 (click for the announcement with more information)](https://medium.com/dartlang/announcing-dart-2-80ba01f43b6#da82) the `new` keyword was made **optional**.

This means that `new Container()` does the exact same as `Container()`.

Comment: Thanks! I also noticed some other mistakes in spelling.The note for the `new` keyword modification also comes very handy for me since i'm just learning the language.

Answer (score 0):

Change import line to this : `import 'package:flutter/material.dart';`

There was mistake in spelling for packafe, instead of package. hope this fixes the issue.